# Use of sqlite3_exec first parameter

Tags: sqlite, visual-c++

I'm trying to call sqlite3_exec() so that the first parameter of the callback function is a pointer to a structure I've defined. Problem is in the callback function when I try to reference the structure, the compiler says "expression must have pointer-to-class type but it has type "void *". I saw another example here that tries to do the same thing, which apparently works but not for me. Code is below, any help appreciated:

```
typedef_struct obj_data {
  int ivalue;
  char cvalue[200];
} OBJ_DATA;

OBJ_DATA adat;


static int callback_Members(void *adat, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    // compile error here on 'adat': expression must have pointer-to-class type but it has type "void *" 
    strcpy(OBJ_DATA *)adat->cvalue, argv[0]);
}


main()
{
// leaving out code to open database, etc.

      sqlite3_exec(db, sql_command, callback_Members, &adat, &ErrMsg);

}
```

Comment: "works but not for me" PLease provide details, compare [ask].

Comment: See above update, let me know if you see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Using `sqlite3_exec()` with a callback that does more than print values is almost always a mistake; use [prepared statements](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) instead.

Comment: You seem to habe misunderstood. I proposed to edit according to [ask], in order to make the question answerable by others. If you found an answer and want to share it that is very welcome. But instead of putting the answer into the question you should better create your own answer post. And you should still try to make sure that the question is answerable by others. Otherwise even with an answer the question does not serve the purpose of StackOverflow, to create a collection of quesitons that are well-asked and useful for everybofy - with good answers.

Comment: `strcpy(OBJ_DATA *)adat->cvalue, argv[0]);` As an initial matter, there are more closing parentheses than opening ones. You probably meant `strcpy( ((OBJ_DATA*)adat)->cvalue, argv[0]);`

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, I don't actually have that in my real code.  And thanks for the clarification on how to ask/answer questions.